# Trying to pass a JSON string with an em dash from Tcl to browser and it fails to parse?

Tags: sqlite, tcl

I've been going in circles a bit the past two days with this simple task due to lack of knowledge in a couple areas; so, this may sound like a repeat of a question from yesterday but it is not.

I had the issue of having a string of plain text stored in SQLite containing an em dash represented by three bytes `226 128 148`. I was trying to search the string for the dash by typing it in the text editor, and could not locate it.

After much help on SO, I learned that the plain text could easily be changed to UTF-8; and I did that and updated the SQLite table column. It now appears as code 8212 if run `scan $c %c`.

Now, the dash is displayed even in the command line interface when run SQLite from there for testing.

However, I can no longer send the record to a web browser to be displayed because of the following error. `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 49 of the JSON data localhost:8000:233:25` Of course, column 49 is the dash.

If I send back the previous version before updating the string from plain text to UTF-8, there is not an error in the browser and the string is displayed as expected.

Likely, this is a very stupid question but I don't know what I'm doing wrong or not doing. Thank you for any guidance you may be able to provide.

I updated one record using a SQLite function.

```
dbt function decodeUTF -argcount 1 -deterministic -directonly -returntype text { encoding convertfrom utf-8 }
set sql {select decodeUTF(text_content) from tablename where conditions...}    
dbt eval $sql
```

And then retrieved the new value and sent it to a browser using some Tcl code as a very limited local server.

```
proc GetSQL {sock} {
  chan flush $sock
  set sql {select text_content from tablename where conditions ... }
  dbt eval $sql {
     set result "{\"result\":\"$text_content\"}"
  }

  set headers ""
  append headers "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
  append headers "Content-Type: application/json; charset: utf-8\n"
  append headers "Content-Length: [string length $result]\n"
  append headers "Connection: Keep-Alive\n"
  puts $sock $headers
  chan configure $sock -translation binary
  puts $sock $result
}
```

The GET request is made using fetch from the browser page script and `return response.json()` is where I think it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `encoding convertfrom utf-8` when storing (your `decodeUTF`) needs to be matched by an `encoding convertto utf-8 $result` upon retrieval, before returning it to the client via your binary-only channel:

```
puts $sock [encoding convertto utf-8 $result]
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense and I was rather stupid. But, I'm still confused by what type of string I have to start off with.  If it has those three characters rather than the 8212, is it or is it not UTF-8? If it is UTF-8, then I suppose regular expressions and string matches in Tcl are one byte at a time?  I, without thinking,  thought I was converting to UTF-8 from plain text (I know it says convertfrom) so that Tcl could use it better and match the dash.

Comment: I haven't fully read your other post, but the main question is how exactly you set up your SQLite database (encoding), what storage class you are using for the column `text_content` (TEXT or BLOB), and how the database was populated? As Donal commented, if you see the three bytes corresponding to the one em-dash character in some string representation in your DB, then this is the problem to tackle.

Comment: Thanks. I'm an idiot.  I stored the strings as binary in SQLite.  The column TEXT but SQLite accepts BLOB in the column. Once I adjust for that, everything works fine.